# re-create the map by angularjs directive of google map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using square theme of angularjs and using their map directive to generate the map like this:

```
<map class="ui-map" zoom="7" center="[32.794065, -97.439365]" style="height:250px !important;" >
</map>
```

This is on search page and work like when user search with any location(text address) it'll automatically generate the pins over to the map accordingly.

Now problem is it generates the pins but not moving or zooming map on the location where pin generated.

**Questions:**

1. Can anyone suggest me how can I do that?
2. Do I need to re-create the map each time on search?
3. If Yes then how can I re-initiliaze the directive from controller
   side?
4. If No then what's the way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a nice search, you can look at the source code from here

http://malix.io/SyrVet/#/

}])

```
    .directive('map', ['$compile', '$templateCache', '$timeout', 'Geo', 'Drive', function($compile, $templateCache, $timeout, Geo, Drive) {
      return {
        restrict: 'C',
        template: '<div>A</div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          dealers: '=',
          search: '=',
          searching: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {

          var body = angular.element(document.querySelector('body'));

          console.log(body);

          var markers = [];
          var center = [-94.2861328, 56.2571657];

          function clearOverlays() {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
              markers[i].setMap(null);
            }
            markers.length = 0;
          }

          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(56.2571657, -94.2861328);//(45.8, -72);
          var myOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(ele[0], myOptions);

          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

          scope.windowInfo = {
            title: 'window',
            desc: 'desc'
          }
          var infoWindowTemplate = $templateCache.get('infoWindowTemplate').trim();
          var infoWindowElem = $compile(infoWindowTemplate)(scope);
          window.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: infoWindowElem[0],
            disableAutoPan: true,
            maxWidth: Math.min(480, window.innerWidth)
          });

          function makeBounds(data) {
            return new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                new google.maps.LatLng(data.southwest.lat,data.southwest.lng),
                new google.maps.LatLng(data.northeast.lat,data.northeast.lng))
          }
          scope.$watch('search', function(a) {
            clearOverlays();
            var code = ('' + a).replace(/ /g, '').toUpperCase();
            if (a && code !== a) {
              scope.search = code;
            }
            if (a && (a.length === 3 || a.length === 6)) {
              scope.searching = true;
              Drive.geocode(a).then(function(data) {
                scope.searching = false;
                if (!data) {
                  scope.search = '';
                  return;
                }
                center = data;
                var postal_rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                  strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                  strokeWeight: 1,
                  fillColor: '#FF0000',
                  fillOpacity: 0.1,
                  map: map,
                  bounds: makeBounds(data[2])});

                markers[markers.length] = postal_rectangle;

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[1], data[0]),
                  title: a.toUpperCase(),
                  icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_black.png'//http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'//'home.png'//'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/arrow.png'
                });
                markers[markers.length] = marker;
                scope.OK = function() {
                  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                  map.setZoom(8);
                  window.infowindow.close();
                }
                scope.dealers.forEach(mapDealer);
                scope.OK();
              });
            }
          });


          var delay = 10;

          function addMarker(dealer, lat, lng) {
            var dist = Geo.distance(center, lat, lng);
            if (dist > 201) return;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
              title: dealer[0]
              //icon:'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(
                marker, 'mousedown', function() {
                  body.addClass('wait');
                  window.infowindow.close();
                  $timeout(function() {
                    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                    map.setZoom(11);
                    scope.windowInfo.title = dealer[0];
                    scope.windowInfo.address = dealer[1].replace('', '');
                    scope.windowInfo.telephone = dealer[2];
                    scope.windowInfo.distance = dist.toFixed(0)
                    window.infowindow.setOptions({maxWidth: Math.min(480, window.innerWidth)});
                    window.infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
                    body.removeClass('wait');
                  }, 100);
                });

            marker.infowindow = infowindow;
            markers[markers.length] = marker;
            marker.orderid = markers.length;
          }

          function mapDealer(dealer, index) {
            var found = !!(dealer, dealer[3] && dealer[3].length && dealer[4] && dealer[4].length && true);
            if (found) {
              delay += 10;
            } else {
              delay += 750;
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
              if (found) {
                addMarker(dealer, parseFloat(dealer[3]), parseFloat(dealer[4]));
              } else {
                var parts = dealer[1].split(/(?:,\s?)/gi);
                var options = {
                  'address': parts[0]
                };
                var code = /([A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9])/gi.exec(dealer[1])[0];
                if (code) {
                  options.componentRestrictions = { postalCode: code,
                    country: 'CA'};
                }
                geocoder.geocode(options, function(results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    dealer[3] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    dealer[4] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

                    console.log(dealer);

                    addMarker(dealer, parseFloat(dealer[3]), parseFloat(dealer[4]));

                  } else {
                    console.log(options, arguments);
                  }
                });
              }
            }, delay);
          };

        }
      };
    }])
;
```

Comment: Hi Malix, Thanks for your response but I've implemented directive from http://angular-google-maps.org/ and working on dragging map at location where marker generates but you worth upvote so giving you my upvote for your good answer.